# How to watermark my logo to 200 videos at once for free?

Tags: windows, video, batch-file, automation, command

I think that command line video editing software + bacth to generate a loop in order to edit all the videos at once is the way to go. My problem is that i have not found free software with command line to insert watermarks so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you're trying to accomplish this with a programming language, this question is off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an [AviSynth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page) script to add a watermark, then use FFmpeg to reconvert the files. FFmpeg for Win32 is capable of reading from AviSynth frameserver.

A helpful link: [How to add a watermark with AviSynth](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/336627-How-to-add-a-watermark-with-AviSynth).

I've written a `/bin/sh` script to help me with family videos batch conversion. It generates windows `.bat` file in your current directory. You could easily modify it to generate your 200 `.avs` scripts and then call FFmpeg to convert them.

```
#!/bin/sh

OUTBAT="$(pwd)/conv.bat"
OUTSH="$(pwd)/conv.sh"

if [ -e "${OUTBAT}" ] ; then
    echo "${OUTBAT}: file exists, exiting"
    exit 4
fi

if [ -e "${OUTSH}" ] ; then
    echo "${OUTSH}: file exists, exiting"
    exit 4
fi

usage() {
    echo "${0}: ${1}"
    echo
    echo "usage: ${0} <mode> <file1>[ <file2> [...]]"
    echo
    echo "available <mode>'s:"
    echo "    -x : generates windows .BAT file (conv. to x264+AAC@mp4)"
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    usage "no mode specified"
    exit 1
fi

MODE=${1}
shift

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    usage "no input files"
    exit 2
fi

while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    FILE=$(echo "${1}" | sed -re 's/\//\\\\/g')
    if [ -n "$(echo "${FILE}" | grep -P '\.mp4$')" ] ; then
        ORIG=$(echo "${FILE}" | sed -re 's/(\.[^\.]*)$/-original\1/')
        echo ren \""${FILE}"\" \""${ORIG}"\" >>"${OUTBAT}"
    else
        ORIG="${FILE}"
    fi
    BASE=$(echo "${FILE}" | sed -re 's/\.[^\.]*$//')
    shift

    case "${MODE}" in
        "-x")
            echo ffmpeg -threads 4 -i \""${ORIG}"\" -vn -af \"aresample=48000:resampler=soxr\" -acodec pcm_s16le \""${BASE}"-audio.wav\" >>"${OUTBAT}"
            echo normalize \""${BASE}"-audio.wav\" >>"${OUTBAT}"
            echo neroAacEnc -if \""${BASE}"-audio.wav\" -of \""${BASE}"-audio.mp4\" >>"${OUTBAT}"
            echo del \""${BASE}"-audio.wav\" >>"${OUTBAT}"
            echo x264 --preset veryslow --tune film --crf 25 --vbv-maxrate 17500 --vbv-bufsize 17500 --level 3.1 -o \""${BASE}"-video.mp4\" \""${ORIG}"\" >>"${OUTBAT}"
            echo mp4box -add \""${BASE}"-video.mp4\" \""${BASE}".mp4\" >>"${OUTBAT}"
            echo mp4box -add \""${BASE}"-audio.mp4\" \""${BASE}".mp4\" >>"${OUTBAT}"
            echo del \""${BASE}"-audio.mp4\" >>"${OUTBAT}"
            echo del \""${BASE}"-video.mp4\" >>"${OUTBAT}"
            echo >>"${OUTBAT}"

            echo cptime \""${ORIG}"\" \""${BASE}".mp4\" >>"${OUTSH}"

            ;;
        *)
            usage "unknown mode"
            exit 3
            ;;
    esac

done
```

You should use it by changing directory to where your video files are and typing `$ script-name *.avi`. `conv.bat` file will be generated with appriopriate commands. As I said: change the part with `echo ffmpeg ...` to suit your needs, but you've got the "framework" to generate `.bat` or `.avs` or what-not file for as many input files as you wish. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot it seems really helpful. I will try to do it with a win batch or use Cygwin and try to run your script modified to my needs. AviSynth seems pretty powerful.

Comment: It is, indeed. I'm glad this was of some help to you. :) Perhaps you'd consider accepting the answer then.